# The sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n + m)}$ for $m \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n + m)}$ for $m \in \mathbb N$

I am thinking about using the p-series test for the part of the denominator containing $n^2,$ but I thin I am wrong, any hints about tackling this problem please?

**EDIT:**
I even do not know how to try to write it as numbers, any help? it is not decomposable using partial fraction so I do not know how to use the telescopic series.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Have you tried telescoping series?

Comment: No. I see you mean use partial fraction first and then telescopic series @Andrei

Comment: But the thing is that I will still have one term containing m and n in the denominator @Andrei

Comment: But it is not decomposable to a partial fraction @Andrei what shall I do?

Comment: @Brain [Of course it is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Apart%5B1%2F%28n%28n%2Bm%29%29%2Cn%5D). All rational functions are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do a partial fraction decomposition first:
$$\frac 1{n(n+m)}=\frac1m\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+m}\right)$$
So then $$m\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n(n+m)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+m}$$
We should write a few terms see if we see a pattern. Say $m=3$:
$$\frac 11+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+...-\frac1{1+3}-\frac 1{2+3}-\frac1{3+3}-...$$
You see that the terms after the first three will cancel out.
For the general case, we rewrite the first sum by splitting it into the first $m$ terms and the rest
$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac 1n+\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac1n-\sum_{n+1}^\infty\frac1{n+m}$$
If we use a variable $j=n-m$, we can rewrite the middle sum as $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{j+m}$$
This is the same as the last sum, so they cancel out.
Putting everything back together:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+m)}=\frac1m\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1n$$

Comment: It would be better to actually write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+m}$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+m}$ cause those don't converge (or use partial sums).

Comment: Thanks @DominikKutek. You are right. I abused a little the notation since it is easier to see how you need to manipulate the sums.